# End of file expected. json(0)

Tags: json

I want to use this JSON file for pandas, but this JSON file has some problem.

I got an error from the time I downloaded it, but I couldn't find the answer.

```
{
    "content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb064277d86016431e33e4e003d/8186c3d1-e9d4-4550-8ec1-a062a7628787___0-26.jpg.jpeg",
    "annotation": [{
        "label": ["Face"],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [{
            "x": 0.08615384615384615,
            "y": 0.3063063063063063
        }, {
            "x": 0.1723076923076923,
            "y": 0.45345345345345345
        }],
        "imageWidth": 650,
        "imageHeight": 333
    }, {
        "label": ["Face"],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [{
            "x": 0.583076923076923,
            "y": 0.2912912912912913
        }, {
            "x": 0.6584615384615384,
            "y": 0.46846846846846846
        }],
        "imageWidth": 650,
        "imageHeight": 333
    }],
    "extras": null
} {
    "content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb064277d86016431e33e4e003d/d1c32c8e-8050-482d-a6c8-b101ccba5b65___0de0ee708a4a47039e441d488615ebb7.png",
    "annotation": [{
        "label": ["Face"],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [{
            "x": 0.7053087757313109,
            "y": 0.23260437375745527
        }, {
            "x": 0.7692307692307693,
            "y": 0.36182902584493043
        }],
        "imageWidth": 1280,
        "imageHeight": 697
    }],
    "extras": null
}
```

It shows this message.

```
Error: Parse error on line 29:
...,    "extras": null} {   "content": "http:
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `null} {` is, as the message suggests, missing something.

Comment: The answer is literally right there in the error message. Read the error, find the line it’s referencing, make the change it is telling you to make.

Answer (score 9):

Try this: it should work!

There's a problem with the way you started your JSON file
Use a square bracket to start and end with a square bracket [ ]

```
[
  {
    "content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb064277d86016431e33e4e003d/8186c3d1-e9d4-4550-8ec1-a062a7628787___0-26.jpg.jpeg",
    "annotation": [{
        "label": ["Face"],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [{
            "x": 0.08615384615384615,
            "y": 0.3063063063063063
        }, {
            "x": 0.1723076923076923,
            "y": 0.45345345345345345
        }],
        "imageWidth": 650,
        "imageHeight": 333
    }, {
        "label": ["Face"],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [{
            "x": 0.583076923076923,
            "y": 0.2912912912912913
        }, {
            "x": 0.6584615384615384,
            "y": 0.46846846846846846
        }],
        "imageWidth": 650,
        "imageHeight": 333
    }],
    "extras": null
} {
    "content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb064277d86016431e33e4e003d/d1c32c8e-8050-482d-a6c8-b101ccba5b65___0de0ee708a4a47039e441d488615ebb7.png",
    "annotation": [{
        "label": ["Face"],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [{
            "x": 0.7053087757313109,
            "y": 0.23260437375745527
        }, {
            "x": 0.7692307692307693,
            "y": 0.36182902584493043
        }],
        "imageWidth": 1280,
        "imageHeight": 697
    }],
    "extras": null
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON structure is wrong. Probably you want get array inside :

```
[
  {
    "content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb064277d86016431e33e4e003d/8186c3d1-e9d4-4550-8ec1-a062a7628787___0-26.jpg.jpeg",
    "annotation": [
      {
        "label": [
          "Face"
        ],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [
          {
            "x": 0.08615384615384615,
            "y": 0.3063063063063063
          },
          {
            "x": 0.1723076923076923,
            "y": 0.45345345345345345
          }
        ],
        "imageWidth": 650,
        "imageHeight": 333
      },
      {
        "label": [
          "Face"
        ],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [
          {
            "x": 0.583076923076923,
            "y": 0.2912912912912913
          },
          {
            "x": 0.6584615384615384,
            "y": 0.46846846846846846
          }
        ],
        "imageWidth": 650,
        "imageHeight": 333
      }
    ],
    "extras": null
  },
  {
    "content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb064277d86016431e33e4e003d/d1c32c8e-8050-482d-a6c8-b101ccba5b65___0de0ee708a4a47039e441d488615ebb7.png",
    "annotation": [
      {
        "label": [
          "Face"
        ],
        "notes": "",
        "points": [
          {
            "x": 0.7053087757313109,
            "y": 0.23260437375745527
          },
          {
            "x": 0.7692307692307693,
            "y": 0.36182902584493043
          }
        ],
        "imageWidth": 1280,
        "imageHeight": 697
      }
    ],
    "extras": null
  }
]
```

Comment: It was an error from saving the file. Thanks man